# Core Data Supporting NSNull

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

Is it at all possible to get Core Data to allow assignment of `NSNull`? I'm using the [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) and it defaults to assigning `NSNull`. I'd prefer to be able to do my deserialization like this:

```
- (void)deserialize:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
  self.name = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Instead of like this:

```
- (void)deserialize:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
   NSNull *null = [NSNull null];
   NSString *value = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
   self.name = (value != null) ? value : nil;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thought would be to create a category for NSDictionary.  The category could then contain this behavior.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible with `CoreData` to do this.

But if code concision if what you are looking for, you could just use macros :

```
#define NULL_NIL(_O) _O != [NSNull null] ? _O : nil
#define DICT_GET(_DICT, _KEY) NULL_NIL([_DICT objectForKey:_KEY])
#define DICT_GET_INT(_DICT, _KEY) [DICT_GET(_DICT, _KEY) intValue]
...
```

Not what I would say *optimized*, but brings concise and readable code :

```
- (void)deserialize:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
  self.name = DICT_GET(dictionary, @"name");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have to deal with multiple collection types (not just dictionaries), you could create a category on NSNull:

```
@implementation NSNull (NSNull_nilIfNull)
+ (id)nilIfNull:(id)object {
    if (object == [self null]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return object;
}
@end
```

Implementation:

```
theValue = [NSNull nilIfNull:[array objectAtIndex:someIndex]];
```

But I must say it adds unnecessary verbosity. I like the idea of using the Vincent G's preprocessor macros to keep the code readable.